# Why I cannot reload/refresh my Fragment in AndroidX?

Tags: android, android-fragments, androidx

I am trying to reload my fragment `FirstFragment` which extends `Fragment` without success. I am getting this error:

[image]

I am using package: `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment` from the library `AndroidX Library`. Is there another way to refresh a `Fragment` in `androidx`? or I misunderstood everything?!! - I don't want to migrate to `Native`/`android.app.Fragment` because I have several `Fragments` to work with.
Any idea how to resolve this error?
I checked the docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/package-summary without finding any help.

Comment: Plz make sure to use the `import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;` import statement and remove the `import android.app.Fragment`

Comment: @Zain I am using `import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;`, `import androidx.annotation.NonNull;` and `import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;`. I am not using `android.app.Fragment`

Comment: Also `import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction` not `import android.app.FragmentTransaction`

Comment: `import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction` is already defined in `import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;`

Comment: cool .. some cleaning-up like `make project`, `File > invalidate caches and restart`

Comment: @Zain Still getting the error after cleaning.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I had to set: `import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;`

Secondly changing (see the code on the image above):

`final FragmentTransaction ft = requireActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();`

to

`final FragmentTransaction ft = requireActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();`

and finally, access my fragment using `findFragmentById()` on my `FragmentManager`; like this:
`Fragment current = requireActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment);`

Afetr that: `ft.detach(current).attach(current).commit();` and it works like a charm.